# Can't look at files in trac codebrowser: "Error: no such changeset"

Tags: svn, trac

I have created a new svn repository

```
sudo svnadmin create /home/qhg4_svn
```

and then imported a project

```
svn import /home/jody/progs/QHG4 svn+ssh://jody@bigfoot/home/qhg4_svn/QHG4/trunk
```

I created a new trac environment (i had a environment with the same name previously, but have deleted it).

```
sudo  trac-admin /home/aim-bigfoot/QHG/TracQHG4 initenv
```

and added the repository

```
sudo  trac-admin /home/aim-bigfoot/QHG/TracQHG4 repository add test /home/qhg4_svn
```

then killed and restarted the trac daemon:

```
sudo  /usr/bin/python /usr/bin/tracd --daemonize --port=8000 /home/aim-bigfoot/QHG/TracQHG4
```

When i point my browser at '''http://my_server:8000/TracQHG4/browser/QHG4''' i can navigate down the directory hierarchy, but when i click an a file, i get the error message **Error: No such changeset** and below this **No changeset 2 in the repository**

How can i fix this problem?

Comment: I was able to solve this issue by doing a ´sync´: ```sudo trac-admin  /home/aim-bigfoot/QHG/TracQHG4  repository sync ""```

Answer (score 0):

For an immediate fix, add the following to the `[repositories]` section of trac.ini.

```
test.type = direct-svnfs
```

That will enable direct access without using a cache. In some case you will see page load performance problems and need to implement [explicit synchronization](https://trac.edgewall.org/wiki/TracRepositoryAdmin#Repositorycaching).